# how to access the service located in minikube from outside

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, nginx-ingress

I've created a service inside a minikube (192.168.64.2) running on my PC (172.10.10.2) and launched an Ingress service, so I can access that service from my PC (172.10.10.2) with minikube ip (192.168.64.2). But I also want to access that service from the other PC (172.10.10.100), how can I achieve this goal?

Comment: you can do port forward and if both PC in same network you can access port over PC IP address. if require you can use nginx.

Comment: @HarshManvar yep, it works. Appreciate it

Comment: Glad to hear that. i have added the answer you can update the status of the question if it's helped or resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do port-forward and if both PC in the same network you can access port over PC IP address. if required you can use Nginx also to access specific routes.

In docker run container with port-forwarding

```
docker run -p 5000:containerport <image name>
```

Get minikube PC IP

access this IP from another PC and use Port : 5000

this will if both in same network. if required you can use nginx.

Update :

if you are on Kubernetes you can use

```
kubectl port-forward svc/<service-name> 5000:<container-port>

kubectl port-forward pod/<pod-name> 5000:<container-port>
```

Comment: ohh yes if you are using Kubernetes i thought you are on docker.